# KineticEval in R programming language

Tags: r

I have some R script and am getting `KineticEval is not available`

I have tried to install using `install.packages("KineticEval")`
but then I get `package ‘KineticEval’ is not available for this version of R`

I can't find which version of R do I need or how to run that script, please help!

I have installed other version but i can't run them in RStudio, i just want to execute my script.

Comment: That package isn’t on CRAN. You need to install it following the instructions from [its development home page](https://github.com/zhenglei-gao/KineticEval).

Comment: But note that package was last updated 7 years ago and was compatible with R 2.15. It seems very unlikely that it will run in a modern version of R. Are you sure you need to run that package?

Comment: Thank you on everything, I have been able to run it, installed a lot of packages and used that from github. 
P.S. working on  R 4.3.2